# Webview for android don't work with Google Maps - blank screen is show instead of a map

Tags: google-maps, android-webview

I'm writing an app that should display a custom Google Maps map within a webview using a GET (or POST) request.
However, the webview component does not display the map, only the customized parts (a table with some custom values calculated within the page).
I thought the problem was the page and decided to test opening the Google Maps website and to my surprise it didn't load either , only blank page without error messages on Logcat.

Using Chrome from my phone all pages are loaded.

I configured network_config_security to accept all connections (avoiding the additional http clear traffic error) only to test as follows:

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

My Android manifest file, using network_security_config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_mob"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_mob_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true">

        <activity android:name="teste.com.br.testevisualizador.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Follow the mainActivity code

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.web_address_edit_text);
        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        forward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
        stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button);
        refresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        homeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm( WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING );
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
            webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true); // enable database storage API
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true); // enable support for multiple windows
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

            webView.loadUrl("https://maps.google.com");

            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                    if (newProgress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (newProgress == 100) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }else{
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

The My WebViewClient class extends from WebViewClient:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        return false;
    }

}
```

I believe that if I can load the main Google Maps page, my map will load.
I've done a lot of research here on Stack and haven't found anything that solves the problem.

thanks in advance